# Communication between uploaded frontend-backend docker images on heroku

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, docker, heroku

I have used a AngularJS frontend, python-flask backend to deploy a ML model on heroku. For this, I have used docker to test it locally and it worked in performing the prediction. However, when I upload the docker images on heroku, the frontend (website) is working, but the communication with python-flask seems to be not working.

The errors from the browser yield:

> [WDS] Disconnected!
>
> ERROR  Object { _body: "Error occured while trying to proxy to:
>   sleepy-bayou-75775.herokuapp.com/api/predict", status: 504, ok: false,
>   statusText: "Gateway Timeout", headers: {…}, type: 2, url:
>   "https://sleepy-bayou-75775.herokuapp.com/api/predict" }
>
> XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Syntax-Fehler Adresse:
>   https://sleepy-bayou-75775.herokuapp.com/api/predict Zeile Nr. 1,
>   Spalte 1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular frontend is not able to connect to Backend APIs. 
It may be due to either backend is not running or you have changed your config file for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the backend is not running.

You can create a new deployment in Heroku for the backend.

Comment: I think that only one container can be pushed to an app, it this possible?